# Coprime Scoreboard and Probability

Tags: probability-theory, number-theory, martingales, markov-process

**In a more Intuitional Description:**

My friends and I were working on a problem of a scoreboard problem. It's a scoreboard that automatically "simplifies" itself (we tend to read $7:2$ as "7 to 2", which makes people think of fractions). Simplified fractions and the original ones are the same, so we want to know what will happen if the scoreboard does the same thing.

Hence, if the current score is $19:15$ and the left team wins a point, it becomes $4:3$ (divided by $5$ on both sides), and if the right-hand side gets a point it goes to $1:1$ (divided by $4$ on both sides). We consider both sides to have an equal chance of winning a point.

Notice, the order of the points matters, if we switch the scoring order from the case above, $19:15$ will firstly become $19:16$, and then $5:4$ (divided by $4$).

The following gives the problem written in a formalized language.

---

**In Formalized Language:**

In an experiment, we let the $0\,$th state be $(0,0)$. For $k\,$th state $(a,b)$, $(k+1)\,$th state has equal probabilities, $50\%$ each, to become
$$\left(\frac{a+1}{\gcd(a+1,b)},\frac{b}{\gcd(a+1,b)}\right)$$
or
$$\left(\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b+1)},\frac{b+1}{\gcd(a,b+1)}\right)$$
where we define $\gcd(0,a)=\gcd(a,0)=a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

We use $f_n(a,b)$ to denote the probability that the $n\,$th state is $(a,b)$, and define $f(a,b)$ by
$$f(a,b)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(a,b).$$
Based on the definitions above, we want to know

- If $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(a,b)$ exists.
- For all $p$ and $q$ satisifying $\gcd\left(p,q\right)=1$, $f\left(p,q\right)=0$ only when $p\cdot q=0$.
- The value of $f\left(1,1\right)$.
- The value of $f\left(p,q\right)$ for all $\gcd\left(p,q\right)=1$, in terms of $p$ and $q$.

---

**Our Current Process:**

Trivially, $$f\left(0,0\right)=f\left(0,1\right)=f\left(1,0\right)=0.$$

And numerically, $$f_{10}\left(1,1\right)=0.2128906250,$$ $$f_{20}\left(1,1\right)=0.1955623627,$$ $$f_{30}\left(1,1\right)=0.1951741818,$$ $$f_{40}\left(1,1\right)=0.1951625187,$$ $$f_{50}\left(1,1\right)=0.1951622049,$$ $$f_{60}\left(1,1\right)=0.1951621955\cdots$$

which does not seem to converge to $0$.

Comment: Indeed, it does appear (experimentally) that this is a positive recurrent Markov chain, with the equilibrium probability of state $(1,1)$ somewhere near $0.2$.  I don't know if this is provable, or if a closed-form expression for this probability is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but some data: I iterated a run of $10$ million states and tallied the data. The limiting distribution looks plausibly close to whatever the actual limiting distribution is:
[image]

Here's some raw data from this run for those interested:

{1, 1}: 1952843 ... {2, 1}: 1471915 ... {1, 2}: 1469527 ... {3, 1}: 864595 ... {1, 3}: 862256 ... {4, 1}: 463755 ... {1, 4}: 461918 ... {3, 2}: 448044 ... {2, 3}: 446685 ... {5, 1}: 239977 ... {1, 5}: 238090 ... {6, 1}: 121992 ... {1, 6}: 120799 ... {5, 2}: 119944 ... {2, 5}: 119157 ... {7, 1}: 61556 ... {5, 3}: 61143 ... {3, 5}: 60688 ... {1, 7}: 60614 ... {8, 1}: 31070 ... {7, 2}: 30736 ... {1, 8}: 30612 ... {5, 4}: 30391 ... {4, 5}: 30347 ... {2, 7}: 30269 ... {9, 1}: 15528 ... {1, 9}: 15388 ... {7, 3}: 15380 ... {3, 7}: 15261 ... {10, 1}: 7843 ... {7, 4}: 7810 ... {4, 7}: 7777 ... {2, 9}: 7762 ... {9, 2}: 7691 ... {1, 10}: 7635 ... {8, 3}: 7583 ... {3, 8}: 7499 ... {7, 5}: 3943 ... {11, 1}: 3903 ... {5, 7}: 3894 ... {1, 11}: 3774 ... {7, 6}: 2004 ... {12, 1}: 1969 ... {6, 7}: 1965 ... {3, 4}: 1965 ... {8, 5}: 1942 ... {11, 2}: 1934 ... {1, 12}: 1933 ... {5, 8}: 1929 ... {4, 3}: 1929 ... {2, 11}: 1841 ... {9, 5}: 997 ... {1, 13}: 992 ... {13, 1}: 990 ... {5, 9}: 976 ... {11, 3}: 961 ... {3, 11}: 923 ... {2, 13}: 523 ... {14, 1}: 510 ... {13, 2}: 480 ... {4, 11}: 470 ... {1, 14}: 469 ... {11, 4}: 465 ... {3, 13}: 274 ... {5, 11}: 268 ... {15, 1}: 252 ... {1, 15}: 235 ... {11, 5}: 225 ... {13, 3}: 224 ... {5, 12}: 148 ... {3, 14}: 143 ... {5, 13}: 136 ... {16, 1}: 134 ... {4, 13}: 131 ... {6, 11}: 120 ... {15, 2}: 118 ... {1, 16}: 118 ... {2, 15}: 117 ... {13, 5}: 116 ... {14, 3}: 114 ... {11, 6}: 114 ... {12, 5}: 111 ... {13, 4}: 110 ... {6, 13}: 69 ... {5, 14}: 67 ... {13, 6}: 61 ... {7, 11}: 59 ... {11, 7}: 58 ... {17, 1}: 57 ... {7, 13}: 56 ... {14, 5}: 55 ... {1, 17}: 51 ... {13, 7}: 35 ... {7, 12}: 34 ... {11, 8}: 30 ... {18, 1}: 29 ... {17, 2}: 28 ... {12, 7}: 28 ... {2, 17}: 27 ... {8, 11}: 25

Comment: A question for your data is why it is not symmetric for $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$, for instance. I'm curious about how your code works, so would you like to share your code with us?

Comment: @JackyWang:  it looks like a random run, so symmetry should be approximate.  It looks to be.

Answer (score 1):

**Author's Process Update**

This is not an answer, and the reason I didn't edit my question is because this is a data-based approach, and is too long for a neat description.

By enumeration, we've coded a C++ program that covered all $2^{60}$ cases with a length of $60$ steps. Here's what we've got.

| $p$ | $q$ | $f_{60}\left(p,q\right)$ or $f_{60}\left(q,p\right)$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $ 1$ | $ 0.1951621955$ |
| $1$ | $ 2$ | $ 0.1469828235$ |
| $1$ | $ 3$ | $ 0.0863545239$ |
| $1$ | $ 4$ | $ 0.0463021500$ |
| $2$ | $ 3$ | $ 0.0447490581$ |
| $1$ | $ 5$ | $ 0.0239345435$ |
| $1$ | $ 6$ | $ 0.0121609998$ |
| $2$ | $ 5$ | $ 0.0119673542$ |
| $1$ | $ 7$ | $ 0.0061289452$ |
| $3$ | $ 5$ | $ 0.0060812358$ |
| $1$ | $ 8$ | $ 0.0030765491$ |
| $2$ | $ 7$ | $ 0.0030765369$ |
| $4$ | $ 5$ | $ 0.0030406561$ |
| $3$ | $ 7$ | $ 0.0015443045$ |
| $1$ | $ 9$ | $ 0.0015412937$ |
| $4$ | $ 7$ | $ 0.0007732846$ |
| $3$ | $ 8$ | $ 0.0007721524$ |
| $1$ | $ 10$ | $0.0007714011$ |
| $2$ | $ 9$ | $ 0.0007710239$ |
| $5$ | $ 7$ | $ 0.0003873967$ |
| $1$ | $ 11$ | $0.0003858891$ |
| $3$ | $ 4$ | $ 0.0001945414$ |
| $6$ | $ 7$ | $ 0.0001938398$ |
| $5$ | $ 8$ | $ 0.0001936984$ |
| $1$ | $ 12$ | $0.0001929917$ |
| $2$ | $ 11$ | $0.0001929446$ |
| $5$ | $ 9$ | $ 0.0000968787$ |
| $1$ | $ 13$ | $0.0000965076$ |
| $3$ | $ 11$ | $0.0000964958$ |
| $1$ | $ 14$ | $0.0000482568$ |
| $2$ | $ 13$ | $0.0000482568$ |
| $4$ | $ 11$ | $0.0000482479$ |
| $1$ | $ 15$ | $0.0000241291$ |
| $3$ | $ 13$ | $0.0000241284$ |
| $5$ | $ 11$ | $0.0000241240$ |
| $1$ | $ 16$ | $0.0000120647$ |
| $2$ | $ 15$ | $0.0000120646$ |
| $4$ | $ 13$ | $0.0000120644$ |
| $3$ | $ 14$ | $0.0000120642$ |
| $5$ | $ 13$ | $0.0000120632$ |
| $5$ | $ 12$ | $0.0000120621$ |
| $6$ | $ 11$ | $0.0000120620$ |
| $7$ | $ 11$ | $0.0000060330$ |
| $1$ | $ 17$ | $0.0000060324$ |
| $5$ | $ 14$ | $0.0000060316$ |
| $6$ | $ 13$ | $0.0000060316$ |
| $7$ | $ 13$ | $0.0000045242$ |
| $7$ | $ 12$ | $0.0000030166$ |
| $8$ | $ 11$ | $0.0000030165$ |
| $1$ | $ 18$ | $0.0000030162$ |
| $2$ | $ 17$ | $0.0000030162$ |
| $8$ | $ 13$ | $0.0000022621$ |
| $9$ | $ 11$ | $0.0000015083$ |
| $1$ | $ 19$ | $0.0000015081$ |
| $3$ | $ 17$ | $0.0000015081$ |
| $9$ | $ 13$ | $0.0000011310$ |
| $10$ | $11$ | $0.0000007542$ |
| $1$ | $ 20$ | $0.0000007541$ |
| $2$ | $ 19$ | $0.0000007541$ |
| $4$ | $ 17$ | $0.0000007541$ |
| $9$ | $ 14$ | $0.0000005655$ |
| $10$ | $13$ | $0.0000005655$ |
| $5$ | $ 6$ | $ 0.0000003778$ |
| $1$ | $ 21$ | $0.0000003770$ |
| $3$ | $ 19$ | $0.0000003770$ |
| $5$ | $ 17$ | $0.0000003770$ |
| $11$ | $13$ | $0.0000002828$ |
| $1$ | $ 22$ | $0.0000001885$ |
| $2$ | $ 21$ | $0.0000001885$ |
| $3$ | $ 20$ | $0.0000001885$ |
| $4$ | $ 19$ | $0.0000001885$ |
| $5$ | $ 18$ | $0.0000001885$ |
| $5$ | $ 19$ | $0.0000001885$ |
| $6$ | $ 17$ | $0.0000001885$ |
| $11$ | $14$ | $0.0000001414$ |
| $12$ | $13$ | $0.0000001414$ |
| $1$ | $ 23$ | $0.0000000943$ |
| $6$ | $ 19$ | $0.0000000943$ |
| $7$ | $ 17$ | $0.0000000943$ |
| $7$ | $ 19$ | $0.0000000707$ |
| $11$ | $15$ | $0.0000000707$ |
| $1$ | $ 24$ | $0.0000000471$ |
| $2$ | $ 23$ | $0.0000000471$ |
| $3$ | $ 10$ | $0.0000000471$ |
| $4$ | $ 9$ | $ 0.0000000471$ |
| $7$ | $ 18$ | $0.0000000471$ |
| $8$ | $ 17$ | $0.0000000471$ |
| $7$ | $ 20$ | $0.0000000353$ |
| $8$ | $ 19$ | $0.0000000353$ |
| $11$ | $16$ | $0.0000000353$ |
| $1$ | $ 25$ | $0.0000000236$ |
| $3$ | $ 23$ | $0.0000000236$ |
| $9$ | $ 17$ | $0.0000000236$ |
| $11$ | $17$ | $0.0000000236$ |
| $9$ | $ 19$ | $0.0000000177$ |
| $1$ | $ 26$ | $0.0000000118$ |
| $2$ | $ 25$ | $0.0000000118$ |
| $4$ | $ 23$ | $0.0000000118$ |
| $10$ | $17$ | $0.0000000118$ |
| $11$ | $18$ | $0.0000000118$ |
| $12$ | $17$ | $0.0000000118$ |
| $11$ | $19$ | $0.0000000103$ |
| $9$ | $ 20$ | $0.0000000088$ |
| $10$ | $19$ | $0.0000000088$ |
| $1$ | $ 27$ | $0.0000000059$ |
| $3$ | $ 25$ | $0.0000000059$ |
| $5$ | $ 23$ | $0.0000000059$ |
| $13$ | $17$ | $0.0000000059$ |
| $11$ | $20$ | $0.0000000052$ |
| $12$ | $19$ | $0.0000000052$ |
| $13$ | $19$ | $0.0000000041$ |
| $7$ | $ 10$ | $0.0000000035$ |
| $1$ | $ 28$ | $0.0000000029$ |
| $2$ | $ 27$ | $0.0000000029$ |
| $3$ | $ 26$ | $0.0000000029$ |
| $4$ | $ 25$ | $0.0000000029$ |
| $5$ | $ 24$ | $0.0000000029$ |
| $6$ | $ 23$ | $0.0000000029$ |
| $7$ | $ 9$ | $ 0.0000000029$ |
| $13$ | $18$ | $0.0000000029$ |
| $14$ | $17$ | $0.0000000029$ |
| $11$ | $21$ | $0.0000000026$ |
| $13$ | $20$ | $0.0000000020$ |
| $14$ | $19$ | $0.0000000020$ |
| $8$ | $ 9$ | $ 0.0000000018$ |
| $1$ | $ 29$ | $0.0000000015$ |
| $7$ | $ 23$ | $0.0000000015$ |
| $15$ | $17$ | $0.0000000015$ |
| $13$ | $21$ | $0.0000000010$ |
| $15$ | $19$ | $0.0000000010$ |
| $1$ | $ 30$ | $0.0000000007$ |
| $2$ | $ 29$ | $0.0000000007$ |
| $7$ | $ 24$ | $0.0000000007$ |
| $8$ | $ 23$ | $0.0000000007$ |
| $16$ | $17$ | $0.0000000007$ |
| $13$ | $22$ | $0.0000000005$ |
| $16$ | $19$ | $0.0000000005$ |
| $1$ | $ 31$ | $0.0000000004$ |
| $3$ | $ 29$ | $0.0000000004$ |
| $7$ | $ 25$ | $0.0000000004$ |
| $9$ | $ 23$ | $0.0000000004$ |
| $13$ | $23$ | $0.0000000003$ |
| $17$ | $19$ | $0.0000000003$ |
| $1$ | $ 32$ | $0.0000000002$ |
| $2$ | $ 31$ | $0.0000000002$ |
| $4$ | $ 29$ | $0.0000000002$ |
| $7$ | $ 26$ | $0.0000000002$ |
| $8$ | $ 25$ | $0.0000000002$ |
| $10$ | $23$ | $0.0000000002$ |
| $1$ | $ 33$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $3$ | $ 31$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $5$ | $ 29$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $7$ | $ 27$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $9$ | $ 10$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $9$ | $ 25$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $11$ | $23$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $13$ | $24$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $13$ | $25$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $14$ | $23$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $15$ | $23$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $17$ | $20$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $17$ | $21$ | $0.0000000001$ |
| $18$ | $19$ | $0.0000000001$ |

And all the other terms that are not mentioned above have a $f_{60}\left(p,q\right)<0.0000000001$.

---

And here's the code.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct score{
    int a;
    int b;
    long long v;
}s[105][10000];
int cnt[105];
long long mp[105][105];
int main(){
    cnt[0]=1;
    s[0][1]=(score){0,0,1};
    for(int i=1;i<=60;i++){  
        memset(mp,0,sizeof(mp));
        for(int j=1;j<=cnt[i-1];j++){
            int d=__gcd(s[i-1][j].a+1,s[i-1][j].b);
            int x=(s[i-1][j].a+1)/d,y=s[i-1][j].b/d;
            if(!mp[x][y]){
                s[i][++cnt[i]]=(score){x,y,0};
            }
            mp[x][y]+=s[i-1][j].v;
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=cnt[i-1];j++){
            int d=__gcd(s[i-1][j].a,s[i-1][j].b+1);
            int x=(s[i-1][j].a)/d,y=(s[i-1][j].b+1)/d;
            if(!mp[x][y]){
                s[i][++cnt[i]]=(score){x,y,0};
            }
            mp[x][y]+=s[i-1][j].v;
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=cnt[i];j++){
            s[i][j].v=mp[s[i][j].a][s[i][j].b];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<34;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<34;j++){
            cout<<"("<<i<<","<<j<<"): ";
            cout<<fixed<<setprecision(10)<<(long double)mp[i][j]/(long double)(pow(2,60))<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Shouldn't $(1,59)$ be on the table somewhere, for instance?

Comment: Yes, it should be somewhere in the table, but our C++ program doesn't support such a high resolution. @GregMartin